# Firebase Cloud Messaging for Multiple domains

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on a website addon that involves registering the website's users into web push notification.

This addon is planned to be installed on multiple domains.

This page says that there is a single `gcm_sender_id` value in the website's manifest json file which should match the registered value on the server:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client

I couldn't find any information regarding registration of multiple `gcm_sender_id` values on the server side in order to allow messaging to different users on multiple domains.

Is that possible using the same Firebase app or would it require me to create a separate app in the Firebase management console manually for each domain I'm installing the addon on?

Comment: I could use some clarification on your use case. If all of the domains will be receiving the same sort of notifications, it makes the most sense to use a single sender ID. You can send these notifications to any domain as long as they have that same sender ID. You could do separate projects and then add multiple projects to your backend, initializing each of them, but that doesn't seem like the best option if I'm understanding your use case.

Comment: Alright, this answers my question (You can send these notifications to any domain as long as they have that same sender ID). If you send an answer I will be able to select it.